# Firebase modules failed to initialize: auth (missing dependency)

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I created a mobile application with unity. For my login I am using the Firebase Email and Password Authentication, After I click the login button this error is coming up on the android device monitor:
05-03 00:18:15.779: E/Unity(28007): InitializationException:  Firebase modules failed to initialize: auth (missing dependency)
05-03 00:18:15.779: E/Unity(28007):   at Firebase.FirebaseApp.CreateAndTrack (Firebase.CreateDelegate createDelegate, Firebase.FirebaseApp existingProxy) [0x00000] in :0 
05-03 00:18:15.779: E/Unity(28007):   at Firebase.FirebaseApp.Create () [0x00000] in :0 
05-03 00:18:15.779: E/Unity(28007):   at Firebase.FirebaseApp.get_DefaultInstance () [0x00000] in :0 
05-03 00:18:15.779: E/Unity(28007):   at Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.get_DefaultInstance () [0x00000] in :0 
05-03 00:18:15.779: E/Unity(28007):   at FirebaseScript.btnLoginClientPressed () [0x00000] in :0 
05-03 00:18:15.779: E/Unity(28007):   at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () [0x00000] in :0 
05-03 00:18:15.779: E/Unity(28007):   at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000] in :0 
05-03 00:18:15.779: E/Unity(28007):   at UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () [0x00000] in :0 
05-03 00:18:15.779: E/Unity(28007):   at UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) [0x00000] in :0 
05-03 00:18:15.779: E/Unity(28007):   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityE

From the emulator of unity the application works fine.